# Extend or Include correct in this scenario?

Tags: include, uml, extend, use-case

**"All current patients will be registered with the new system and receive notification of their registration."**

[image]

1. I took register patient as the first use case here. Always after registering patient happens they send a notification. So I used extend. To show that registering process extends to send notification.(In my case I thought registering is the most important).
   So I drew like this.

   Is that a correct diagram?
2. Someone else says it should be an include.

I don't understand why that person takes send notification as the main use case. Is this even correct? Please explain. 
In the scenario it says when a patient registration happens then only notification is sent.

Please explain the difference here. Is the second diagram correct? And what is the best to use?

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that `Send notification` is a use case at all. If for any reason it were one, your first drawing is correct. The second is simply non-sense. The 2nd would need to reverse the direction to be somehow meaningful.

```
A -<<include>>-> B
```

means that B will always appear somewhere in A.

```
B -<<extend>>-> A
```

means that B will optionally appear somewhere in A.

Anyway, the use of those is a sign of functional decomposition. And that is plain wrong. Use cases must show added value for an actor. Nothing else.

Comment: I wonder how use case synthesis is taught at schools. Obviously from people that do not have an idea about the matter from a practical use. This is really a pity.

Comment: According to my use case what is A and B?

Comment: Send notification is B, Register patient is A

Comment: ya So like A <<include>> --> B is incorrect right.
Since Registerpatient <<include>> -->  Send Notification is not what scenario says. It says registration happens first. Then only the notification sent. 
So it can only take extend isn't it?

Comment: Actor is definitely connected to A (Register patient) . So we cant take B -<<extend>>---> A. If we get that it means, after send notification Registration happens, it is also not right, I feel it should only be A -<<extend>>-> B where Register patient extends send notification. Am I not correct?